# Запуск скрипта sh в Python c правами супер пользователя

Tags: python, bash, permissions, sh, root

Как запустить скрипт в sh  в Python c root-правами код на python : `#!/usr/bin/env python   from subprocess import check_call  line ='test  check_call(['./ne.sh','line])` .  Код скрипта: `#!/bin/bash  groupadd $1 usermod -aG $1 user id user`  - если коротко :скрипт создаёт новую группу и добавляет туда пользователя с именем user ,а после выводит список групп user . После запуска выдаёт ошибку : Permission denied. Как   встроить в скрипт выдачу рут прав или что-то подобное в Python ?

Comment: Через su или sudo, видимо?

Comment: Спасибо ,а если я  добавлю формы ,то всё так же через sudo можно будет запускать или что-то придумывать придётся ?

Comment: Вопрос исчерпан ,всё оказалось куда проще ,чем думал ) Спасибо вам !)